# Mysterious fail within Python 2.7.5 argparse.add_argument() with custom formatter_class

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to write a subclass of HelpFormatter to use with argparse. The formatter is easy; integrating it as a subclass isn't. I found a very helpful example at stackoverflow.com/questions/3853722/, in an answer from Anthon.

Using Python 2.7.5 on Mac OS X 10.9.4. When I try to subclass HelpFormatter, I keep getting:

```
./testBlankLineHelpFormatter.py -q
******* LOADING MY CLASS
Instantiating argparse.ArgumentParser
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./testBlankLineHelpFormatter.py", line 15, in <module>
    formatter_class=BlankLineHelpFormatter
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1600, in __init__
    help=_('show this help message and exit'))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1293, in add_argument
    raise ValueError("length of metavar tuple does not match nargs")
ValueError: length of metavar tuple does not match nargs
```

*** Note that the error is while instantiating my subclass, when the standard class tries to add a "--help" item -- it never gets to any of my add_argument() calls. I trimmed my subclass down to just this, and it still fails:

```
class BlankLineHelpFormatter(argparse.HelpFormatter):
    """
A formatter for argparse that just respects blank lines (as in, doesn't
wrap across them).

See also: http://bugs.python.org/issue12806

"""

    sys.stderr.write("******* LOADING MY CLASS\n")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        sys.stderr.write("******* IN MY INIT\n")
        super(BlankLineHelpFormatter, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
```

*** I'm running it with a driver I also trimmed way down, to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
from __future__ import print_function
import argparse
import BlankLineHelpFormatter

print("Instantiating argparse.ArgumentParser")

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="""
This work is licensed under a Creative Commons
Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported License. For further information on
this license, look it up.
    """,
    formatter_class=BlankLineHelpFormatter
)

print("Adding --quiet\n")
parser.add_argument(
    "--quiet", "-q",      action='store_true',
    help='Suppress most messages.')

print("Instantiated, now trying parse_args")
args = parser.parse_args()

print("Back.")

print("You might want to try '-h'...")

sys.exit(0)
```

I looked at the argparse library source, and the problem doesn't make sense to me even in context. Is this a bug preventing subclassing HelpFormatter, or am I missing something in my tiny bit of remaining code?

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Your code shows `import BlankLineHelpFormatter` and then `formatter_class=BlankLineHelpFormatter`, which suggests you're passing a module rather than an actual formatter class there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing a `BlankLineHelpFormatter` module as the formatter, rather than the `BlankLineHelpFormatter` class. The error message comes from [this part of the `argparse` source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/argparse.py#l1294):

```
        # raise an error if the metavar does not match the type
        if hasattr(self, "_get_formatter"):
            try:
                self._get_formatter()._format_args(action, None)
            except TypeError:
                raise ValueError("length of metavar tuple does not match nargs")
```

`_get_formatter()` tries to call the module to create a formatter, then misinterprets the resulting `TypeError` as something else.

The fix should be to specify

```
formatter_class=BlankLineHelpFormatter.BlankLineHelpFormatter
```

Comment: The `parser` was doing the equivalent of `add_argument('-h',...)`, and testing its arguments by trying to format its `help` line.  But it hit a problem in `_get_formatter` before getting to `_format_args`.  Hence the confusing error message.

Answer (score 0):

In case of interest, the formatters for argparse are now working and available at http://derose.net/steve/utilities/PY/MarkupHelpFormatter.py (CCLI Attribution-Share-alike license). Thanks again to @user2357112 for helping earlier!

These classes format for ANSI terminals. Not highly polished (for example, auto-numbering is unfinished), but you may find them helpful.

"MarkupHelpFormatter" supports much of the mediaWiki, MarkDown, and POD syntaxes (even intermixed):

```
import MarkupHelpFormatter
MarkupHelpFormatter.InputOptions["mediawiki"] = True
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="""...your text, with mediawiki markup...""",
    epilog='...',
    formatter_class=MarkupHelpFormatter.MarkupHelpFormatter
)
```

"ParagraphHelpFormatter" merely wraps text like the default argparse formatter, except that it respects blank lines. Bug reports, fixes, enhancements, etc. welcome.